# Contact Form 7 sometimes doesn't work

Tags: wordpress

My Contact Form 7 in some period of time doesn't work in other works fine.

I am getting message:
Failed to send your message. Please try later or contact the administrator by another method

I tried to debug this and found that CF7 will call wp_mail.

It will call this code from Contact Form 7:

```
if ( $send ) {
    return @wp_mail( $recipient, $subject, $body, $headers, $attachments );
}
```

But this will return false.

Hase anyone some idea what can be problem.

**EDIT:**

When it call wp_mail it will throw error in this part of wordpress code:

```
if (!$this->smtp->data($header . $body)) {
   throw new phpmailerException($this->lang('data_not_accepted'), self::STOP_CRITICAL);
}
```

**EDIT:**

This data function will at the first line will call function "sendComand":

```
public function data($msg_data)
{
    if (!$this->sendCommand('DATA', 'DATA', 354)) {
        return false;
    }
    .....
```

It will failm in this if statment.

Here is sendCommand function:

```
protected function sendCommand($command, $commandstring, $expect)
{
    if (!$this->connected()) {
        $this->error = array(
            "error" => "Called $command without being connected"
        );
        return false;
    }
    $this->client_send($commandstring . self::CRLF);

    $reply = $this->get_lines();
    $code = substr($reply, 0, 3);

    if ($this->do_debug >= 2) {
        $this->edebug('SMTP -> FROM SERVER:' . $reply);
    }

    if (!in_array($code, (array)$expect)) {
        $this->last_reply = null;
        $this->error = array(
            "error" => "$command command failed",
            "smtp_code" => $code,
            "detail" => substr($reply, 4)
        );
        if ($this->do_debug >= 1) {
            $this->edebug(
                'SMTP -> ERROR: ' . $this->error['error'] . ': ' . $reply
            );
        }
        return false;
    }.......
```

and this will fail in this last if statment, this condition in if (!in_array($code, (array)$expect)) will be true.

So $expect was provided on sendCommand function call:

```
$this->sendCommand('DATA', 'DATA', 354)
(array)$expect) == Array([0] => 354)
```

and $code we will get from get_lines() function:

```
 $reply = $this->get_lines();
 $code = substr($reply, 0, 3);
```

When it fail in $reply is next value:

```
 $reply = 550 5.4.5 Daily sending quota exceeded. u1sm14669850qat.27 - gsmtp
```

And here is get_lines() source:

https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-smtp.php#L820

Comment: Unless you've configured WordPress to use an SMTP server to send mail, I believe wp_mail is just a wrapper around PHP's built in `mail` function. So, if that returns false (maybe the server doesn't like sending unauthenticated messages?), then wp_mail will return false too. Maybe run some tests with the `mail` function?

Comment: It use SMTP I tried to debug wp_mail and what I got now it throw error in this part:

`if (!$this->smtp->data($header . $body)) {
            throw new phpmailerException($this->lang('data_not_accepted'), self::STOP_CRITICAL);
        }`

Comment: It looks like the `data` method sends the message to the SMTP server. Checkout [the source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-smtp.php#L481). My guess is your server doesn't like something about the message. I would go through the `data` function and find exactly where it's failing.

Comment: @DominicP please check my last edit and let me know if you have some idea

Comment: Good job debugging that. I think you have your answer right there. Your SMTP server has a sending quota (probably an anti-spam feature), and you've run into it. That also explains why the problem is intermittent (it will work until the quota is reached). The only solution I can see here is to find another SMTP server to use with a higher quota or find a way to get your quota lifted. You might also want to look into how many messages your form is sending. Unless it's a lot, it's odd that you would be hitting a quota. Maybe some spammer is abusing your form?

Comment: Yea, you are right. I changed SMTP server and now it's fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this issue before and resolved it by switching to gmail's smtp by using this plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/faq/

All you need to set it up is a gmail account, if this is a client/work website, you can create a free account with gmail and simply enter it in the plugin settings.

Comment: I also resolved this problem by switching to gmail's smtp. Thanks.